# rapidjson: parse a string of arrays to document

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have a string with arrays (of arrays of arrays) of floats and need to parse that as value into a rapidjson document (object) to a specified key.. I tried this (note, that `doc` already exists from way up in the code, but doesn't matter for the sake of the example..), but somehow this messes with the first float in the first sub-array:

```cpp
// An array is supplied via string
auto str = "[[[13.38625361, 52.4652558], [13.38625361, 52.48000128]]]"

rapidjson::Document d, doc;
d.Parse(str);
auto v = rapidjson::GetValueByPointer(d, "");
rapidjson::Pointer("/avoid_polygons").Set(doc, *v);
```

The resulting `doc` has the `avoid_polygon` key, but the value is not *quite* right:

`"avoid_polygons":[[[4.6389747880982e-310,52.4652558],[13.38625361,52.48000128]]]`

Anyone knows what's going on here? Or if there's a better/easier way to parse the string directly in the `doc`'s `avoid_polygon` key without the detour over another document?

Comment: Using a debugger would be a good idea for that kind of problem.

Comment: I did and can't say I got much out of it.. I think this is more a conceptual mistake. somehow that first value is just a garbled mess. how would you go about using gdb on this specific problem?

Comment: Well, tracing the code line by line including rapidjson top-level code and validate at each step might give an hint where data get corrupted. Well, if `str` is already a valid json and you only want to add `"avoid_polygons":` in from of it and write that to a file, using a json library is somewhat overkill.